Coverting rotational to linear movement
What are the different methods to covert rotational to linear motion in the example below?
The servo motor will rotate causing the metal rod to move in a linear motion as seen below.
Linear motion change is will be in the order of milliseconds


I believe the device you're looking for is called a leadscrew:

A leadscrew (or lead screw), also known as a power screw or translation screw, is a screw used as a linkage in a machine, to translate turning motion into linear motion.

The article goes on to list ball screws and roller screws as alternatives to the leadscrew, but I'm in the group of people that would call those types of leadscrews.

Thanks, I am looking for a system that moves the rod backwards and forward several times per second this system looks like for a much slower revolution

@Jimmy3421 the linkage is a linkage, it doesn't have a concept of "slow" or "fast." If you're concerned about your system's ability to perform then you can do a quick calculation. If you have an oscillating system with speed profile $A\sin(\omega t)$ then your acceleration profile is the first derivative, or $A \omega \cos(\omega t)$. The peak acceleration would be when $cos(\omega t) = 1$, which means $A \omega$. Assume some efficiency in the linkage like 70%, and then your motor needs to be able to provide $(1/0.7) * (A \omega)$.

The linkage itself will have some inertia that you'll need to take into account if it's close to the inertia of your load, but if that's the case then probably you'll also need to take into account the motor's rotor. Leadscrews are how virtually all electric linear actuators are setup, which is essentially what you're asking to create.

Thanks for the info
